# 'None of the files were in this project content' in Android Studio(flutter)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, refactoring, extract

I try to Extract Method in Android Studio and an error occurred
error is 'None of the files were in this project content: ~~'

[image: Error screenshot]

this is the code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_todolist_app/constants/colors.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: toBGColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: toBGColor,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
          Icon(
            Icons.menu,
            color: toBlack,
            size:30,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 40,
            width: 40,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              child:Image.asset('assets/images/avatar.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),

      body: Container(
        child: Text('This is home screen.'),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I try shortcut key, and right clicking the widget name and choosing Refactor > Extract.
But both show the same error.

thank you for reading.